# How to create a custom Iq stanza using smack in android

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I want to create an iq stanza like below to achieve MUC/SUB for MUC in ejabberd, as smack 4.2.3(android) is not providing any predefined function for MUC/SUB.

```
 <iq from='hag66@shakespeare.example'
        to='coven@muc.shakespeare.example'
        type='set'
        id='E6E10350-76CF-40C6-B91B-1EA08C332FC7'>   
 <subscribe xmlns='urn:xmpp:mucsub:0'
             nick='mynick'
             password='roompassword'>
    <event node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:messages'/>
    <event node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:affiliations'/>
    <event node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:subject'/>
    <event node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:config'/>  
  </subscribe> 
  </iq>
```